# Merge Velocities of Two Aircraft

Tags: trigonometry

**INTRO**

**Scroll down to skip to question with all data provided. Picture of aircraft at end of post.**

Simple question here guys if y'all are willing to help. I'm looking for the formulas and possible a little instruction if the formulas are difficult. I'm a math novice, I am the majority of my math instruction came in high school. I would like to calculate the answer myself as opposed to just have it answer for me.

Thanks!
CSAR

**BACKGROUND**

Flying into ATL yesterday, I noticed that the airport had aircraft landing on parallel runways. My aircraft(MD-11) landed on a heading of  270. The parallel aircraft (Boeing 777) landed on a heading of 260.

The distance between the two runways is **1,680 m**

MD-11 approach velocity is **73.56 m/s**

777 approach velocity is **76.652**

**Question**

How do I calculate the time it would take for these two aircraft to merge (collide?)

**On a 360 degree radial, one object is moving on 270 degrees at 73.56 m/s, the other is moving on 260 degrees 76.652 m/s. They began 1,680 m apart.**

I would also like to calculate how quickly they would merge if one the 777 is off course and is travelling on the 250 degree, 240 degree, etc.

***THANKS!***

[image: 777 on parallel approach at KATL with Georgia Dome in background.]

Comment: If the runways are parallel, how can the aircraft collide? How can they land at different headings if the runways are parallel? And is the distance between the two runways measured at the start? The end?

Comment: @shardulc:  The runways are "parallel", but oriented 10 degrees from each other.  Presumably the distance is somewhere along the runways, but we can just take that as the initial perpendicular separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A figure is below.  If you assume the separation is almost perpendicular to the paths of flight, you can cut the $10^\circ$ angle with a bisector and find the length of the long sides from trigonometry.  $\frac {1680}2= L\sin 5^\circ, L=\frac {840}{\sin 5^\circ}, L=9638m$, which takes about $128$ seconds (using $75$ m/sec as a rough average).

[image]

But they won't hit unless they arrive at the vertex at the same time.  To do that, you need $AB=\frac {76.652}{73.56}AC\approx 1.042AC$  You can try this in the law of cosines:  $1680^2=AB^2+AC^2-2(AB)(AC)\cos 10^\circ=2.084AC^2-2.084AC^2\cos10^\circ$ gives $AC \approx 9441$ and the time is $\frac {9441}{73.56}\approx 128.4$ seconds.  Not too different.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! First formula is an easily understandable. The second formula will take a little more time for me to understand. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

With your information, this is what you want to solve:

$$73.56 t=76.652 \cos{10^{\circ}} t\\
-1680+76.652\sin{10^{\circ}}t=0$$

As you can see, they might not collide.

If the 777 flies at degree $240^{\circ}$, you can just change the $10$ to $30$.